# Insert labels over only a few bars in the histogram in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, labeling

I am drawing a histogram with the following code

```
set style data histogram
#clustered
#set terminal wxt enhanced persist
set term post eps enhanced "Times-Roman, 14"
set output 'tostack.eps'    #change here
#set boxwidth 0.9 
set grid
set auto y
#set auto x
set auto y
#set ylabel format "{/:Bold}"
#set size 1.35,0.35
#set title ""
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title offset 1,0.25
set ylabel "\nXXX (in %)\n\n" font "Times-Roman ,25"     #change here
set xlabel "\nYYY \n" font "Times-Roman,25"                 #change here
#set style fill solid noborder
set style fill pattern  border -1
set key right
set key spacing 3 font "Times-Roman,20"
set xtics font ", 20"
set ytics font ", 20"

plot for [COL=2:5] 'tostack.dat' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader fs pattern 2
```

And my data file is

```
AA  BB      CC      DD      EE
100 23.6491500555   6.9743235667    6.5497090218    6.9819639165
200 6.4522741669    14.0817294443   15.1392548608   4.4619875307
300 8.8030456951    8.1386311242    12.5224139497   6.7637627586
400 25.7698157655   7.6673254026    10.0040799765   11.7883595409
```

In the histogram that got generated, how could I insert the labels for only those bars that is  larger values in each group.

Also pl hellp me in making those labels bold.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the largest value in each group, it will be most likely necessary to use an external processing tool. One might for example use gawk as shown below. The idea is to skip the header (condition `NR>1`) and in each row to find the column number with the maximum (assuming that your data file has 4 data columns, this number will be either 2, 3, 4, or 5). Now, in the histogram, individual groups of boxes are centered consecutively at 0,1,2, etc. With 4 data columns (and `boxwidth` set to 1), the width of each box is 0.2 (4 boxes between two centers of each group + one empty box for the "space"). In order to find the x-coordinate where to place the label, it is therefore necessary to transform the numbers `2,3,4,5` into `b-0.3,b-0.1,b+0.1,b+0.3`, where b denotes the 0-based number of the group:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced "Times-Roman" 14
set output 'tostack.eps'

set grid

set boxwidth 1.0
set style data histogram
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title offset 1,0.25

set ylabel "XXX (in %)" font "Times-Roman, 25"
set xlabel "YYY" font "Times-Roman, 25"

set style fill pattern border -1
set key right
set key spacing 3 font "Times-Roman, 20"

set xtics font ",20"
set ytics font ",20"

plot \
    for [COL=2:5] 'tostack.dat' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader fs pattern 2, \
    "<gawk 'NR>1{ \
        j=0; \
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ \
            if(i == 2 || $i > m){ \
                m=$i;j=i; \
            } \
        } \
        print (NR-2)+(0.2*j-0.7), m; \
    }' tostack.dat" u 1:2:(sprintf("%.3f", column(2))) t "" w labels offset 0,char 1 font "Times-Bold, 16"
```

This then produces:
[image]

EDIT:
In case should the maximum be chosen within each column, it is just necessary to slightly modify the filtering script (the idea behind the calculation of the label position stays the same):

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced "Times-Roman" 14
set output 'tostack.eps'

set grid

set boxwidth 1.0
set style data histogram
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title offset 1,0.25

set ylabel "XXX (in %)" font "Times-Roman, 25"
set xlabel "YYY" font "Times-Roman, 25"

set style fill pattern border -1
set key right
set key spacing 3 font "Times-Roman, 20"

set xtics font ",20"
set ytics font ",20"

plot \
    for [COL=2:5] 'tostack.dat' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader fs pattern 2, \
    "<gawk '\
        NR>1{ \
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ \
                if(NR == 2 || $i > m[i-2]){ \
                    m[i-2]=$i; \
                    p[i-2]=NR-2; \
                } \
            } \
        } \
        END{ \
            for(i=0;i<4;i++){ \
                print p[i] + (0.2*i - 0.3), m[i]; \
            } \
        } \
    ' tostack.dat" u 1:2:(sprintf("%.1f", $2)) t "" w labels offset char 0,char 0.5 font "Times-Bold, 12" rotate by 0
```

which produces:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, ewcz. In the question, I mentioned "each group" to mean in each column of the data file. I am planning to plot the % increase of the different methods BB,CC...., for different sizes(100,200,...). So, I wish to tell the person seeing the graph about the size that gave the maximum % increase for each of the methods.

Comment: Thank You, but the code shows a warning message, and does not print the labels. The warning is    ` "fromstack.plot", line 36: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points  `           
I have the valid data file in that directory. Not able to guess what went wrong!

Comment: interesting, which Gnuplot version / platform are you using? the data file format is the same as in your question?

Comment: I am using version -4.4.3, and I have Ubuntu 12.04. The data file format is the same as it is in the question.

Comment: could you try to replace `gawk` with `awk`? I guess that `gawk` is not installed on Ubuntu by default...

Comment: Hurray! It worked! Thanks a lot!! I was having a comment line in the data file earlier and that was the culprit!!